# Naming arguments in Wolfram functions?

Tags: functions

Sometimes you have functions with very long argument lists:

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := c
```

so is there a way to "name" these arguments (order insensitive) so that users can know what they're getting more easily? In pseudo-code:

```
f[c = "what I'm getting", a = 1, b = 2, d = 0, e = 1]
```

This is similar to "record syntax" in other programming languages.

Comment: This is precisely what [options management](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OptionsManagement.html) does. You end up with `f["WhatImGetting" -> 5, "TheMainThing" -> 8, "SomethingElse" -> 77]` as usual with options.

Comment: @MassDefect Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Oops, thanks for letting me know. I don't know how I managed to copy it like that. This is the one I was thinking of: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html

Comment: You could define `f` to work with associations too.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an example for how to combine [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html), [`OptionsPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html), and [`OptionValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html):

First, define the available options for `f` and their default values:

```
Options[f] = {"TheMainOption" -> 0,
              "SomeOtherOption" -> 7, 
              "TheLetter" -> "A"};
```

Then, define the function `f` (here: make a list of all option values, in a particular order that is independent of the order in which the user specifies the options in the function call):

```
f[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue["TheMainOption"],
                        OptionValue["SomeOtherOption"],
                        OptionValue["TheLetter"]}
```

Note that by default, `OptionsPattern[]` looks up the available options and defaults from the associated definition of `Options[f]`.

**Tests:** the options can be given in any order, and default values are provided in the definition of `Options[f]`:

```
f[]
(*    {0, 7, "A"}    *)

f["TheLetter" -> "Z"]
(*    {0, 7, "Z"}    *)

f["TheLetter" -> "N", "SomeOtherOption" -> -2]
(*    {0, -2, "N"}    *)
```

Remind me what the options and defaults were for `f`?

```
Options[f]
(*    {"TheMainOption" -> 0, "SomeOtherOption" -> 7, "TheLetter" -> "A"}    *)
```